# Working with Git under Typo3

Tags: git, content-management-system, web

I work with several developers on websites using Typo3 CMS at the same time and I was thinking of using Git so that we could all work together without overwriting each others work, but I've run into a few problems, and I wonder if you guys could give me some insights:

- I was thinking of installing a local webserver for everyone on the team, but then the database is not accessible from outside the live webserver, so that means that we have to make a copy of the webserver. Then there is the problem of, how to keep the database up to date between the developers (for example, adding an extension)
- We have to add several variables like BASEURL for the project to work properly on each developer#s workstation

This was only 15 minutes right on the task, but it immediately made me question:

- Is it practical to use VCS for developing websites between several developers?

Comment: VC might be a bit tricky to setup at first (especially with moving DBs etc), but either way it will pay dividends throughout your project, whereas using no VC will only help you to accumulate [technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt).

Comment: But how should I confront all those changes that I have to do in order to make it work in my machine? I dont want pushing them to the live server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should checkout gitosis to setup on git server accessible over the network
2. For your environment problem :

   1. Try to uniformize development environment as much as possible
   2. Use the ignore feature of your VCS to ignore file that are supposed to handle only local changes

Comment: But what to do when those things cant be done, for example setting the base url in the index.php

Comment: for this example you can accept that this base url is the same for every dev (through virtual for example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify which parameters are used to differentiate between the local and live environments, and in which files. This is really a separate issue from the use of VCS, although a common practice is to have a template settings file (the name can be slightly different from the actual file to avoid confusion) in version control that have configurations for multiple environments, but only one (usually local) set to active at any point in time.

```
### local ###
port=8080

### production ###
# port=80
```

Another scheme is to put such environment-specific config files in the respective config/env folders, and reference them accordingly.

```
config/local/config.properties
config/production/config.properties
```

Comment: That is not the issue. The issue is that keeping up with the changes in the database and other variables makes "push" and "pull" a more complicated operation.

Comment: How is that so? You only push/pull content that should be pushed/pulled. For database changes you can either track that using a schema file, or a more elaborate scheme of data migration patches. The team should know when and how to update the variables when the config files in known locations have been updated.

Comment: I have no idea what a schema file is or a data migration patch, but if I have to start worrying about stuff to mantain this system of developing, I think I rather stay on the old "everyone writing on the same server" system :S  :S

Comment: Then your problem is more than just a version control system. What is your plan when that server or database goes down?